# Delete EMPTY Directory or folders / subfolders

Tags: file, gradle, directory, isnullorempty

I have the following folders/files.

```
A/B/C/D/giga.txt
A/BB/
A/CC/DD/fifa.jpg
A/ZZZ/1/a.txt
A/ZZZ/2/b.png
A/ZZZ/3/
```

How can I code in Gradle/Groovy to delete ONLY the empty directories/subfolders.
i.e. Delete "A/BB", "A/ZZZ/3" in the above sample example. Real case has lot of such folders.

I tried

```
tasks.withType(Delete) { includeEmptyDirs = true }
```

didn't work

```
tasks.withType(Delete) { includeEmptyDirs = false }
```

didn't work

I don't want to use Gradle > calling > Ant way as that'd be my last resort. Also, don't want to delete each empty folder by writing explicit delete statement per empty folder.

Case 2:
If I run the following:

```
delete fileTree (dir: "A", include: "**/*.txt")
```

this above cmd will remove any .txt file under folder A and any subfolder under it. Now, this will make "A/ZZZ/1" a valid candidate for "empty folder" which I would want to delete as well.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [Javadoc for FileTree](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/index.html?org/gradle/api/file/FileTree.html), consider the following to delete empty dirs under "A". Uses Gradle 1.11:

```
task deleteEmptyDirs() {
    def emptyDirs = []

    fileTree (dir: "A").visit { def fileVisitDetails ->
        def file = fileVisitDetails.file

        if (file.isDirectory() && (file.list().length == 0)) {
            emptyDirs << file
        }
    }    

    emptyDirs.each { dir -> dir.delete() }
}
```

Comment: For cases where directories aren't actually deleted, replacing `it.delete()` with `project.delete(it)` solves this problem. In my case I was deleting empty source directories.

Comment: This will delete the deepest empty directories, but not the directories that contain them.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to delete all the folders that themselves only contain empty folders, this code might help.

```
    def emptyDirs = []

    project.fileTree(dir: destdir).visit { 
        def File f = it.file

        if (f.isDirectory() ) {
            def children = project.fileTree(f).filter { it.isFile() }.files
            if (children.size() == 0) {
                emptyDirs << f
            }
        }
    }

    // reverse so that we do the deepest folders first
    emptyDirs.reverseEach { it.delete() }
```

Comment: For cases where directories aren't actually deleted, replacing `it.delete()` with `project.delete(it)` solves this problem. In my case I was deleting empty source directories.